# how to write informations into mifare ultra light EV1 nfc card with android?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

i have succeeded to write informations into my nfc card but now it does not work anymore, here is my code :

```
  public void writeTag(MifareUltralight mifareUlTag) {
    try {
        mifareUlTag.connect();
        String val=getRandomString();

       // mifareUlTag.writePage(4, "rfa".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
       // mifareUlTag.writePage(5, "nfc".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
        mifareUlTag.writePage(10, val.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
        //mifareUlTag.writePage(7, " now".getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException while writing MifareUltralight...", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            mifareUlTag.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException while closing MifareUltralight...", e);
        }
    }
}
```

the error that happens is : `android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost`
the `getRandomString` method is a function whiche returns a random string of 3 characters.
my card is working again because i can read his number.

Comment: What method are you using to get notified about a Tag `enableForegroundDispatch` or `enableReaderMode`?

Comment: enableForegroundDispatch

Answer (score 0):

I found that with real users it was very easy to get `TagLostException` or `IOException` with `enableForegroundDispatch` when doing anything other than reading Ndef data, especially trying to write data.

The reason is simple, with `enableForegroundDispatch` you don't control the notification sound.

Users were hearing and removing the Tag from the RF field too early, with `enableForegroundDispatch` the sound is generated when the system NFC App has detected a Tag, it then has to craft the `Intent`, pause and resume your App to be able to deliver that `Intent`, your App has to process that `Intent` and then start writing to the Tag.

I found it much more reliable to use `enableReaderMode` where you can turn off the System App notification sound and make your own sound when you have finished writing to the Tag. `enableReaderMode` also does not pause and resume your App but instead the Tag reading is handled in a new thread, this is generally less overhead and quicker thus lead to a lower chance of errors like `TagLostException`

Of course these errors can still be generated and your code has to handle these and with `enableReaderMode` you can generate a "failure" sound to prompt the user to represent the Tag or as I do be silent on any error and just retry the write when the Tag is presented again.

`enableReaderMode` just provides a more robust and less confusing interaction for the user than `enableForegroundDispatch`

**update:**

Have you tried writing 4 chars as the data send must be 4 bytes, you are probably not sending enough data.

Comment: tried to use enableReaderMode but the error is remaining the same

Comment: i tried with this example *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64441412/unable-to-trigger-intent-on-nfc-read-using-with-locktaskmode*

Answer (score 0):

You might have to be careful that you aren't timing-out the transceive function of the NFC chip. IF you are debugging and have a break-point in the middle of your write operation, you may be causing a timeout error.